# Relationships between 2-3 models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have following models:

### User

> has_many :roles, :through => :assignments

### Role

> has_many :assignments
>   has_many :users, :through => :assignments

### Assignment

> belongs_to :user
>     belongs_to :role

Whole evening I am trying to find a way, how to print somewhere, what kind of role has currently log in user.
I tried already stuffs like

> @log_in_user.roles.type_of_role

or

> @log_in_user.assignments.type_of_role

but unfortunately nothing succes... Could anyone give me any idea how get this information?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Provided your logged-in user is `@user`, you should be able to do `@user.roles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
@log_in_user.roles.map(&:type_of_role)
```

That will return an array of the `type_of_role` attribute for each role the user has.